# SharePoint 2010 REST API JQUery Insert, Update, Delete

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Can anyone explain or point me to a link with samples of doing Update, Delete using Jquery with the SharePoint 2010 Rest API?

I have the insert working and of course queries since the MSDN documentation explains and every tutorial on the net explains queries but just wondering if anyone ever inserts, updates, deletes data instead of only samples and tutorials on querying? Yes I know I can use the CSOM but I want to learn how this is done via jquery and sharepoint rest?

Also I want to use Merge for updating.

Here's the working insert code:

```
function insertMilestone() {
            var mileStonesListUrl = "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Milestones";    
               var milestone = {};
               milestone.Title = "Testing from REST";

               var entry = JSON.stringify(milestone);

               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: mileStonesListUrl,
                   data: entry,
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   error: function (xhr) {
                       alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                   },

                   success: function () {
                       getAll();

                   }
               });
           }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recently worked with the REST API for SP 2013, as a Example POC that can be used for any call implementation i.e. JQuery, C# etc.

***Using POSTMAN***

*First get your digest token:*

A method was found on this site : http://tech.bool.se/basic-rest-request-sharepoint-using-postman/​
*[Credit where credit is due]*

**POST**

```
http://<SharePoint Domain Url>/sites/<Site name>/_api/contextinfo
```

**Header:**

```
Accept : application/json;odata=verbose
```

**Body:**
Clear the body ​

From the payload use "FormDigestValue" value and put it into your headers with the key : X-RequestDigest when making actions that alter items in SharePoint.

**Reading data:**

**GET**

```
http://<SharePoint Domain Url>/sites/<Site name>/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Sites/<Site Name>/Shared Documents/My Folder')/files?$select=Name
```

**Headers:**

```
Accept : application/json;odata=verbose​
```

When it comes to create, update , delete you need the digest token or an authorization token to perform these actions, this token is highlighted at the begining to to retrieve.

**​Creating Data**
**POST**

```
http://<SharePoint Domain Url>/sites/<Site Name>/_api/web/folders​
```

**Headers:**

```
Accept : application/json;odata=verbose

X-RequestDigest : 'GUID looking toking'

Content-Type : application/json;odata=verbose
```

**Body:**

```
{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': '/Sites/<Site Name>/Shared Documents/Some Folder/POC3'}​
```

**Note:**
*'ServerRelativeUrl' the folder on the end POC3 is the folder that I want to create*

**Related resources:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380(v=office.15).aspx

***Note:*** PostMan was used for this example and other application may need you to url encode the endpoint.

The above Request Structure can be used for all requests, the related resource highlights some of the standard methods that can be used with the REST Api

Comment: This is for 2013, not 2010. 2010 uses `/_vti_bin/ListData.svc`, not `/_api/web/folders​`.  And you'd want `/_api/web/lists`, anyway, in 2013.  Giving pieces instead of a working example, and handing off reference links isn't how we want to answer questions.

Comment: Thank you @vapcguy for the feedback, this was answered in 2014, This was one of my first answers and would have created a repository if I knew better back then

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should've figured that, since it was 5 yrs ago.  I just wanted to make sure others knew the differences in the APIs and call attention to it in case you (and others that might see it) were still answering similarly. Glad you've grown as the time passed. Peace.

Answer (score 21):

### How to perform CRUD operations using SharePoint 2010 REST Interface

**Create**

In order to  perform a Create operation via REST, you must perform the following actions:

- Create an HTTP request using the `POST` verb.
- Use the service URL of the list to which you want to add an entity as
  the target for the POST.
- Set the content type to `application/json`.
- Serialize the JSON objects that represent your new list items as a
  string, and add this value to the request body

JavaScript example:

```
function createListItem(webUrl,listName, itemProperties, success, failure) {

    $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName,
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data.responseJSON.error);
        }
    });
}
```

Usage

```
var taskProperties = {
    'TaskName': 'Order Approval',
    'AssignedToId': 12
};

createListItem('https://contoso.sharepoint.com/project/','Tasks',taskProperties,function(task){
    console.log('Task' + task.TaskName + ' has been created'); 
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

**Read**

In order to  perform a Read operation via REST, you must perform the following actions:

- Create an HTTP request using the GET verb.
- Use the service URL of the list item to which you want to add an
  entity as the target for the GET.
- Set the content type to `application/json`.

JavaScript example:

```
function getListItemById(webUrl,listName, itemId, success, failure) {
    var url = webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName + "(" + itemId + ")";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data.responseJSON.error);
        }
    });
}
```

Usage

```
getListItemById('https://contoso.sharepoint.com/project/','Tasks',2,function(taskItem){
    console.log(taskItem.TaskName); 
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

**Update**

To  update an existing entity, you must perform the following actions:

- Create an `HTTP` request using the `POST` verb.
- Add an `X-HTTP-Method` header with a value of `MERGE`.
- Use the service URL of the list item you want to update as the target
  for the `POST`
- Add an `If-Match` header with a value of the entity’s original ETag.

JavaScript example:

```
function updateListItem(webUrl,listName,itemId,itemProperties,success, failure)
{
   getListItemById(webUrl,listName,itemId,function(item){

      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: item.__metadata.uri,
         contentType: 'application/json',
         processData: false,
         headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": item.__metadata.etag
         },
         data: Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(itemProperties),
         success: function (data) {
                success(data);
         },
         error: function (data) {
                failure(data);
         }
      });

   },
   function(error){
       failure(error);
   });

}
```

Usage

```
var taskProperties = {
    'TaskName': 'Approval',
    'AssignedToId': 12  
};


updateListItem('https://contoso.sharepoint.com/project/','Tasks',2,taskProperties,function(item){
    console.log('Task has been updated'); 
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

**Delete**

To  delete an  entity, you must perform the following actions:

- Create an HTTP request using the `POST` verb.
- Add an `X-HTTP-Method` header with a value of `DELETE`.
- Use the service URL of the list item you want to update as the target
  for the POST
- Add an `If-Match` header with a value of the entity’s original ETag.

JavaScript example:

```
function deleteListItem(webUrl, listName, itemId, success, failure) {
    getListItemById(webUrl,listName,itemId,function(item){
        $.ajax({
            url: item.__metadata.uri,
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-Http-Method": "DELETE",
                "If-Match": item.__metadata.etag
            },
            success: function (data) {
                success();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                failure(data.responseJSON.error);
            }
        });
    },
   function (error) {
       failure(error);
   });
}
```

Usage

```
deleteListItem('https://contoso.sharepoint.com/project/','Tasks',3,function(){
    console.log('Task has been deleted'); 
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

Please follow [List Items manipulation via REST API in SharePoint 2010](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/03/22/list-items-manipulation-via-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2010/) article for a more details.

Comment: I want to add the attachment, How can I add multiple attachments with SharePoint 2010 REST Interface?

Answer (score 9):

Here is the update and delete, it wasn't as hard as I thought it was going to be and it works. 
Hopefully this will help someone out because there is so much bogus information on using the REST API and I see a zillion posts on querying but none on Insert, Update, Delete.

```
//update
           function updateMilestone(id) {

               var mileStonesUrl = "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Milestones";
               mileStonesUrl = mileStonesUrl + "(" + id+ ")";


               var beforeSendFunction;

               var milestoneModifications = {};
               milestoneModifications.Title = "Updated from REST";

               var updatedMilestoneData = JSON.stringify(milestoneModifications);


               //update exsiting milestone
               beforeSendFunction = function (xhr) {
                   xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Match", "*");
                   // Using MERGE so that the entire entity doesn't need to be sent over the wire.
                   xhr.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", 'MERGE');
               }

               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   processData: false,
                   beforeSend: beforeSendFunction,
                   url: mileStonesUrl,
                   data: updatedMilestoneData,
                   dataType: "json",
                   error: function (xhr) {
                       alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                   },

                   success: function () {
                       alert("Updated");
                       getAll();

                   }
               });




     function deleteMilestone(id) {

               var mileStonesUrl = "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Milestones";
               mileStonesUrl = mileStonesUrl + "(" + id+ ")";

               $.ajax({
                   type: "DELETE",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   processData: false,                       
                   url: mileStonesUrl,                     
                   error: function (xhr) {
                       alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                   },
                   success: function () {
                       alert("deleted");
                       getAll();

                   }
               });

           }




           }
```

Comment: Have you tried this:http://spservices.codeplex.com/ it is awesome if you want to use javascript to talk to Sharepoint

Comment: Yes, I've seen the spservices but it's uses the CSOM and xml and all that jazz, CSOM is not that difficult, U2U CAML builder for the queries makes it easy. 

It's cool but using the REST API with jquery is really awesome. I'm really trying to learn the inner workings instead of abstracting all the learning with using someone elses library, I would rather code my own framework, I don't have time constraints and it's nice understanding all of it.

I didn't understand REST merge but now I do. I have jquery datatables with custom UI and pretty much a single page application inside sharepoint.

Comment: I'm surprised when I google all the examples are all for Gets and the rest are for SPServices. Doesn't anyone use the REST API ? Why are there no posts on CRUD, even the SP Pluralsight Course the author stops on geting data.

Comment: I am doing Single Apps as well inside SharePoint. The first thing I did was hookup Service Stack to it and do my own implementation using Server Object Model. It works pretty, Add knockout, Sammy and Require to that and it's win all over the place

Comment: Nice, I've been learning Service Stack and actually was planning on doing the same thing since we have a lot of external databases. I'll have to checkout Sammy, haven't used that before.

Comment: Cool , let me know if you need a hand at some stage. inputflip {at} gmail {dot} com

Comment: Hi Vadim Gremyachev.Do you have some solution for upload attachment file to custom list use rest api and javascript?

Comment: I do, also I've switced to using the SharePoint PNP.js framework which makes using the rest api easy.

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Files