# SharePoint 2010 REST jQuery Update

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to update a single value of a list item in SharePoint 2010 using REST and jQuery. So far, I haven't gotten anything to work. I've looked at many posts and MSDN articles. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820779/sharepoint-2010-rest-api-jquery-insert-update-delete) to a post that claims to work, but it fails with "500: Internal Server Error". Below is my version of the code
To be clear, I need to do everything from the client, and would prefer to use REST over SPServices method.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
src="https://http://[path removed]/jquery.json-2.4.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

//update
           function updateProject(id) {
               var projectUrl = "http://[path removed]/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ProjectManagement";
               projectUrl = projectUrl + "(" + id+ ")";
               var beforeSendFunction;  
               var projectModifications = {};
               projectModifications.Title = "Test Update Performed";
               //var updatedProjectData = JSON.stringify(projectModifications);
               var updatedProjectData = $.toJSON(projectModifications); 
               //update exsiting project
               beforeSendFunction = function (xhr) {
                   xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Match", "*");
                   // Using MERGE so that the entire entity doesn't need to be sent over the wire.
                   xhr.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", 'MERGE');
               };

               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   processData: false,
                   beforeSend: beforeSendFunction,
                   url: projectUrl,
                   data: updatedProjectData,
                   dataType: "json",
                   error: function (xhr) {
                       alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                   },

                   success: function () {
                       alert("Updated");
                       getAll();
                       }
               });
           }    
</script>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divarea">This is a test page</div>
<button onclick="updateProject(2523);">Update!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible issue that I've found in your example is related with List Item object `projectModifications`, the error occurs when List Item entity does not contain the specified property (in your case `Title`).

For example, in case of OOTB Tasks list ( entity `Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.TasksItem`) you should specify `TaskName` property:

```
var taskProperties = {
        'TaskName': 'Approval'
    };
```

So, the solution, make sure that you specify the correct property.

In addition, you could print the detailed error message like this:

```
error: function (xhr) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.responseJSON.error));
}
```

---

Below is provided the common function for performing an `Update` operation

```
function updateListItem(webUrl,listName,itemId,itemProperties,success, failure)
{ 
      var itemUrl = webUrl + "_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName + "(" + itemId + ")"; 
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: itemUrl,
         contentType: 'application/json',
         processData: false,
         headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": "*" 
         },
         data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
         success: function () {
                success();
         },
         error: function (data) {
                failure(data.responseJSON.error);
         }
      });

}


//Usage: how to update Task Name (Title) in Tasks list  
var taskProperties = {
    'TaskName': 'Approval'
};


updateListItem('https://contoso.sharepoint.com/project/','Tasks',17,taskProperties,function(){
    console.log('Task has been updated'); 
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

### References

Please follow an article [List Items manipulation via REST API in SharePoint 2010](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/03/22/list-items-manipulation-via-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2010/) that contains a description of CRUD operations for SharePoint 2010 REST API.

Comment: Wow! That worked! I've been trying all sorts of adjustments to the code I posted, but when I used your example it worked the first time. Many thanks! I wish I knew what the problem was with the old code.

Comment: Great, glad to hear :)

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out the add/update for item with a multiple select lookups. Any examples on that?