# Update sharepoint status list item using web service

Tags: sharepoint, vbscript

I am using an old SharePoint 2010 product.

Inside my site, I created a Status list which looks like this:

[image: Status list]

I found some Web Service API method which allows me to update some records like `UpdateListItems()` or `UpdateList()`

Can you please tell me how to build an update request to update the Status field based on the CaseNumber# field?

Comment: Please check this Vadim Gremyachev reply at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820779/sharepoint-2010-rest-api-jquery-insert-update-delete

Answer (score 0):

We can use listdata.svc to update list item based on the casenumber field. The following example code for your reference, modify the variables and add the code into a content editor web part, click the button to update list item.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateListItem() {
    var siteUrl="http://sp2010";
    var listName="StatusList";
    var caseNumber="456798";
    var itemProperties={
        'Status': 'Approval'
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/"+listName+"?$filter=CaseNumber eq '"+caseNumber+"'",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {          
            var item=data.d.results[0];
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: item.__metadata.uri,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                processData: false,
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                    "If-Match": item.__metadata.etag
                },
                data: Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(itemProperties),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("succeeded."); 
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
          });
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="update list item" onclick="updateListItem()"/>
```

[image]